# How to do soft assertion in pytest-bdd

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, bdd, pytest-bdd

Is it possible to do soft assertions in pytest-bdd framwork.

Its working without bdd. But with pytest-bdd plug in it fails with below error.
(Same test case works fine if I dont use --soft-asserts)

```
INTERNALERROR>     scenarios(pytest.FEATURE_FILE(__file__))
INTERNALERROR> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\username\\PycharmProjects\\Bitbucket\\Lambda\\GCP\\GCP_feature\\automation_testsuite\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\pybdd\\scenario.feature'
================================================================= no tests ran in 0.60s ================================================================== 
| filepath | function | SUBTOTAL |
| -------- | -------- | -------: |
| TOTAL    |          |        0 |
```